# Prove that if ${\{{a_n}^2}\}$ converges (${\{a_n}\}$ is monotone), thus ${\{a_n}\}$ converges and to what?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

From Fitzpatrick's Advanced Calculus book: "Suppose that the sequence ${\{a_n}\}$ is monotone, i.e., either monotonically increasing or decreasing. Prove that ${\{a_n}\}$ converges if and only if ${\{{a_n}^2}\}$ converges. Show that this result does not hold without the monotonicity assumption."

It is easy to show to that ${\{{a_n}^2}\}$ converges if ${\{a_n}\}$ converges: ${\{a_n}\}$ is convergent sequence and ${\{a_n}\}$ also, since product of two convergent sequences converges (to the product of their limit), so ${\{{a_n}^2}\}={\{a_n\times a_n}\}$ converges; and it doesn't require that ${\{a_n}\}$ to be monotone.

On the other hand, it is not general true to say that ${\{a_n}\}$ converges if ${\{{a_n}}^2\}$ converges; ${\{a_n}\}={\{(-1)^n}\}$ is a counterexample.

What remains to evaluate (i.e., my questions) is that:

$1-$ Prove that if ${\{{a_n}^2}\}$ converges and if ${\{a_n}\}$ is monotone, thus ${\{a_n}\}$ converges.

And,

$2-$ If ${\{{a_n}^2}\}$ converges to $a^2$, to which of $a$ or $-a$ does ${\{a_n}\}$ converge?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If $\{a_n^2\}$ converges, it is bounded. Then $\{a_n\}$ is bounded and monotone.
2. Anything can happen. There is no way to know a priori.

Comment: Yes, The Monotone Convergence Theorem ! I can see that both of $a$ and $-a$ are possible; is there a way to prove that the limit of ${\{a_n}\}$ is only a member of ${\{a, -a}\}$?

Comment: If $a_n\to\ell$ then $a_n^2\to\ell^2=a^2$.

Comment: How do you show if ${\{a_n^2\}}$ is bounded then ${\{a_n\}}$ is bounded also?

Comment: @Sunny $|a_n|^2\le M\implies |a_n|\le\sqrt M$.

Answer (score 0):

if {$a_n^2$} converges, then it is bounded; then $\exists M \in \Re$ such that |$a_n^2$| $\le$ M. Hence |$a_n$| $\le \sqrt{M} $, and therefore $a_n$ is bounded.

Then by the theorem (one Fitzpatrick's textbook has shown in the chapter), if a sequence $a_n$ is monotone, then it converges iff it is bounded.
We've just proven $a_n$ is bounded, with given $a_n$ is monotone, so we know $a_n$ converges.

Further from that theorem, if $a_n$ is monotone increasing then $a_n$ converges to sup($a_n$), if monotone decreasing, $a_n$ converges to inf($a_n$).
Not necessarily to $a$ or $-a$ though, i suppose.

Comment: HI, welcome to MSE. May I ask for you to use MathJax to format your equations? Here is a page for you to understand it: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=2&tab=scoredesc#tab-top